# Peltier quick heating and cooling

Tags: control-system, temperature, pid-controller, peltier, closed-loop

I am using a Peltier module to quickly heat and cool down the object placed on it to a particular temperature. My target is to heat the object to 90° and then cool it down to 54° and then heat it again to 70° and continue this cycle.

I will be using a PID temperature controller to control the temperature of the Peltier module. I want the temperature change to be 5°/s.

Does the high temperature change rate depend on the Peltier module or the PID controller? If the temperature change rate depends on the PID controller, how does the Peltier react to these high temperature change rates?

Comment: Are peltier modules known for fast temperature changes?

Comment: *Does the high temperature change rate depend on the Peltier module or the PID controller ?* You need to get a better understanding of how such a system physically works. If the PID controller (which is just that, a **controller**) limits the speed of change then what would happen if the PID controller was "infinitely fast". I know that doesn't exist but suppose it was 10x faster than the speed of the Peltier elements. Would that make the Peltier elements "go faster"?

Comment: Also, your 5 degrees / second requirement is utterly unrealistic if you ask me. Go search for very fast professional (and very expensive) heating/cooling plates and see what rate those can manage. Can they manage 5 degrees / second? Also realize that heating/cooling a grain of rice takes much less energy than heating / cooling a large block of concrete. Look up "heat capacity".

Comment: Think how crazy energy rate you need to raise 5 degrees in a second.  Take 100 g water as the example 'object'.

Comment: I have a Hofer(Aldi) coolbox with a selector switch: cool or heat (I don't know who needs this feature). The manual says that you have to wait to cool down before inverting the Peltier mode, else it will  destroy it ... if it might help.

Comment: Are those Celcius degrees or Freedom/Fahrenheit degrees?

Comment: Might want to think more in terms of a physical heat-pump, and a (much) colder and hotter source for it.  It also matters if the medium is air, physically contacted, liquid, etc. Unless sealed, air will absorb moisture when heated, and condense when cooled...

Answer (score 3):

Consider four tanks of water, solenoid valves, and/or brushless pumps instead.
Maintain two tanks at 54 and 90 degrees, and keep the others chilled and hot respectively.

Use the chilled and hot tanks for temperature rise and fall, and the others to maintain the steady temperatures. Keep the volume of the manifold and heat exchanger as small as you can.

You will have to undertake the calculations to verify that your chilled and hot supplies can add/remove heat energy fast enough to move the thermal mass of manifold, heat exchanger, and sample, fast enough to meet requirements.

If your 90 degree temperature is Celcius, you don't have much headroom at the hot end unless you pressurise the system (which adds dangers of its own) but at the cold end you may just need a cold tap connection instead of a chiller; the opposite applies if you use Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 2):

A Peltier element can wear out. It's the expansion and contraction that occurs with thermal cycling that eventually leads to the elements de-bonding from the plates. Frequent and rapid cycling is particularly bad.

5 ° per second is a very challenging rate of temperature change. The only way you'll approach this is to have two water baths, one at each temperature, and physically transfer your specimen between them. As an alternative, route a heat transfer fluid to exchange coils on your specimen from either your hot or cold reservoir.

Peltiers operate at quite low power, whether heating or cooling, far too little to approach your target temperature change rate.

Depending whether your low temperature is 54 °C or 54 °F, it may be better to use a resistive heater and passive or fluid cooling. You won't have the wear-out problem, and you will be able to get far greater heating power than you would with a Peltier.

Your controller will not influence how fast your can ramp your specimen's temperature if the limitation is the heating or cooling power available.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that should be clear is that you only have a chance to achieve these temperature ramps if you add no thermal load to the regulated side. That means only a small bonded temperature sensor and a small specimen.

5 K/s is still challenging.

I have operated Peltiers for years with a limit of 1 K/s because I experienced reliability problems at higher rates. It is possible power-wise but I guess the temperature becomes uneven which will eventually lead to stress cracking in the junctions and thus element failure.

You may get slightly better results if you bring the heat-sinked side to something like 50-60°C so the temperature difference is not as big.

Answer (score -3):

The speed of temperatuer rise depends of heat lose. You have to cover other sides well with thermal insulators. If the  speed is low you have to use few chips, from few sides. The main problem is  when you heat one side the other side get cool. That will absobe some heat from heating side.Therefor you should seperate two sides well, that is the issue,  If supply voltage is increased abow 12 v the speed will go up. Please get the data sheet and refer to it.I think using a heating element and a fan is efficient than this chips. Becase you cant connect them directly to mains. Need a transformer. Other thing that you dont't want to heat and cool simultaneously. So efficiency goes low.Heating element is low in price.

Comment: *The speed of temperatuer rise depends of heat lose* No, you need to learn about "heat capacity" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity  If what you write is true then a metal box would heat up equally fast if I keep it empty (filled with air) or if I fill it with water. In the case that the box is filled with water heating will take longer as the water absobs much more heat than air. Water has a higher **heat capacity**.

Comment: In this problem heat capacity dosn't change.He says "the object" .I learned about heat capacity in 1979